# How To: Filter A Query on All Lists Based on Title Contains

Tags: javascript, csom, caml-query, caml, jquery-ajax

I have queried all of the lists within a subsite but need to filter based on criteria in the title.

I then need to display the filtered list contents. Is this possible if the list contents are not all the same?

Thank you in advance SP community!

This is what I have so far, it is not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var siteUrl = 'https://myportal/mysite/mysubsite';

// Load the required SharePoint libraries.
$(document).ready(function () {

    // The js files are in a URL in the form:
    // web_url/_layouts/15/resource_file
    var scriptbase =  siteUrl  + "/_layouts/15/";

    // Load the js files and continue to
    // the execOperation function.
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js",
        function () {
            $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", execOperation);
        }
    );
});

// Function to execute basic operations.
function execOperation() {

    // Continue program flow here.
     retrieveWebSiteProperties(siteUrl);

}

function retrieveWebSiteProperties(siteUrl) {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    this.oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
    this.collList = oWebsite.get_lists();
    this.listInfoCollection = clientContext.load(collList);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
}

 function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    var listInfo = '';
    var listEnumerator = this.collList.getEnumerator();
    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oList = listEnumerator.get_current();
       if(oList.get_title().indexOf("pro") !== -1){ //if title contains "pro"
       listInfo += 'Title: ' + oList.get_title() + ' Created: ' + 
oList.get_created().toString() + '\n';
            }
        }

        $("#chartArea").html(listInfo);

    }

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

</script>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: nope, console errors :/ just a blank page

Comment: See my answer below; it is possible that your code is not executing because of collisions w/ jQuery. Can you add a console.log somewhere in $().ready(...) to be sure it's running?

Answer (score 0):

First- are you running this code on a page that inherits from a SharePoint master page? Or is your code "outside" of SharePoint? Also, are you using SharePoint Online or SharePoint Server? (For my examples below I'm using SP Server 2016).

I would suggest not using `$(document).ready`, because this can collide with SharePoint's own methods for delaying script execution (and leave you with no way of knowing in which order code will execute). Instead use `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push()` ([Reference](http://www.stephanrocks.com/2011/10/05/_spbodyonloadfunctionnames-in-sharepoint-vs-jquerys-document-ready/)), which does a good job of delaying script execution until after the body loads.

**Edit**: the only SP native library you need here is `SP.js` which provides the `ClientContext` object. This library is automatically declared as a dependency early on in the Master Page:
[image: RegisterSod() is called on SP.js early in the master page]

Since this call to `RegisterSod()` is already being made, we don't need to call it again; instead we can just go ahead and use `SP.SOD.executeFunc()` with a reference to 'sp.js', which ensures that that script is available before our code runs. This is actually simpler than my original solution, because you don't even need to specify where `SP.js` is located- SharePoint already knows, because of the earlier call to `RegisterSod('SP.js')`:

```
    SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", "SP.ClientContext", function () {
        // This will run after sp.js is loaded.
        retrieveWebSiteProperties(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl);
    });
```

I made some changes to your code and was successfully able to run it on my Dev farm. Here is my setup:

- Test.aspx -> SharePoint Page containing a Content Editor Web Part pointing to test.html
- test.html -> Regular HTML file stored in ~/SiteAssets. You can see the complete contents here: https://gist.github.com/codegard1/a5023ec6c5f6405a9c3e5e5f9db7549e

This is the output: 
[image: Output from running the script in SharePoint]

[Reference for SP.SOD methods](http://www.ilovesharepoint.com/2010/08/sharepoint-scripts-on-demand-spsod.html)

**Edit 2**
You can also get List names & list items using REST. The idiom is actually a lot easier to use than JSOM, and it is very easy to implement with jQuery. This will *not* work as expected in SharePoint Online:

```
// Set the REST endpoint to use. 
// This one includes a filter to only return lists whose title includes "Site"
var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists?$filter=substringof('Site', Title)";

// Create the AJAX request using jQuery. All you need to specify are the endpoint and the right headers to get back JSON
var request = jQuery.ajax({ url: url, headers: { "Accept": "Application/json;odata=nometadata" } });

// Use a .then() callback to do something with the data after it it returned by the server
request.then(
    function (d) {
        // For each result in the set of returned data
        d.value.forEach(
            function (i) {
                // Print the Title of the list to the console
                console.log(i.Title);
            });
    });
```

Comment: I replaced my $(document).ready function and my execOperation() function with your code but no luck :/ did I miss something?

Comment: Can you diagnose where the code is falling down using `console.log()`? I would suggest that if `initialize()` is firing that you try getting rid of the SP.SOD code and just try calling `retrieveWebSiteProperties()` immediately.

Comment: @Torybee I ran your code as a test and was able to get it to work. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, really insightful information you've provided. I used your code, (in a CEWP pointing to the html file) and still no luck. I am running this code on a page that inherits a master page, on SP 2013. The only other thing I've got in the HTML doc are these script links: <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"/>
I don't currently see how but - could they be interfering?

Comment: Glad it's somewhat helpful / Sorry it's still not working. `MicrosoftAjax` is probably redundant- I'm pretty sure it was replaced by jQuery, unless you need it for a specific reason. I'm using jQuery-1.8.1 in my own farm, FWIW. At this point I would settle for just getting any kind of feedback in the console. Try putting a call to `retrieveWebSiteProperties()` inside a `setTimeout()` with a 5 or 10 second delay. If it doesn't work after 10 seconds of the page being fully loaded then the problem is not with the lazy-loading code or dependencies.

Comment: @Torybee see my second Edit above. If this way is not working for you then you might try using REST instead.